# JS: given a string, change all the symbols between the first and the last letters of each word of the string if the word starts and ends with 'a'

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Example:

```
aza asssa axxxa rrra -> a!a a!!!a a!!!a rrra
```

So far I've come up with this solution:

```
const argument = "aza asssa axxxa rrra";

const amount_of_spaces = [...argument].filter(x => x === " ").length;

let j = 0;

const argument__clone = [...argument];

const space__indices = [];

function do__stuff() {
    while (j < amount_of_spaces) {
        space__indices.push(argument__clone.indexOf(" ") + j);
        argument__clone.splice((argument__clone.indexOf(" ")), 1);
        j++;
        do__stuff();
    }
};

do__stuff();

const words = [];

let word = '';

for (let i = 0; i < argument.length; i++) {
    if (!(space__indices.includes(i))) {
        word += argument[i];
    }
    else {
        words.push(word);
        word = '';
    }
}

words.push(word);

let new__word = '';

const new__words = [];

const words__static = [];

for (i of words) {
    if (i[0] === 'a' && i[i.length - 1] === 'a') {
        for (let j = 1; j < i.length - 1; j++) {
            new__word += "!";
        }
        new__words.push(new__word);
        new__word = '';
    }
    else {
        words__static.push(i);
    }

}

new__words.map(i => "a" + i + "a");

console.log(new__words);

console.log(words__static);
```

So one array stores the indices of spaces and the other one stores the words from the given string. We can separate the words because we know when one ends because we have the array with space indices. Then we check for each word whether it starts with 'a' and ends with 'a'. If the requirements are met we change all the letters within the word for "!" (excluding the very first and the very last ones). If the requirements are not met we store the word into the other array.
Eventually we have two arrays that I want to concatenate into one. The problems is if I was given something like this:

```
aza asssa rrra axxxa
```

It wouldn't have worked because of the order

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression would be simpler. Match an `a` after a word boundary, match more non-space characters, and finally match another `a` followed by a word boundary.

```js
const input = 'aza asssa axxxa rrra';
const output = input.replace(
  /(?<=\ba)\S+(?=a\b)/g,
  interiorWord => '!'.repeat(interiorWord.length)
);
console.log(output);
```

For a more manual approach, split the input by spaces so you have an array of words, then for each word, check if it begins and ends with an `a` - if so, construct a new word by checking the old word's length. Then turn the array back into a single string.

```js
const input = 'aza asssa axxxa rrra';
const words = input.split(' ');
const replacedWords = words.map(word => (
  word[0] === 'a' && word[word.length - 1] === 'a' && word.length >= 3
    ? 'a' + '!'.repeat(word.length - 2) + 'a'
    : word
));
const output = replacedWords.join(' ');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What does '/(?<=\ba)\S+(?=a\b)/g' mean? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: `(?<=\ba)` looks behind for a word boundary, followed by an `a`. `\S+` matches non-space characters. `(?=a\b)` looks ahead for an `a` followed by a word boundary. You can look up https://www.google.com/search?q=learning+regular+expressions